# Kendo UI DataSource in SharePoint Add-in throws o._detachObservableParents is not a function

Tags: sharepoint, kendo-ui, sharepoint-addin

I'm developing my first SharePoint hosted add-in with Kendo UI and getting the following exception when I run it:

o._detachObservableParents is not a function

I've tried instantiating the object with as little configuration as possible to make sure it's not one of the settings that I'm messing up but I keep getting the same error.

Searching online has produced no clues at all.

---

**Technical Details**

Kendo UI v2016.2.714
SharePoint Online (I believe it's 2013)
The following code shows how I've added the resources to the Add-in page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/Fabric/4.0.0/fabric.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.common-office365.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.office365.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Content/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.dataviz.office365.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/kendo/2016.2.714/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/repositories.js"></script>

    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
```

---

### **Edits**

**Edit 1** - Note: I can instantiate simple components like buttons and calendars without any issues.